# Cant generate text fields dynamically Javascript onChange

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, textfield, onchange

I am having trouble with generating text fields dynamically. I have a select box in the form and what I want to do is to create text fields on the basis of selection of number in drop down list. So if the user selects one I want to create one text field below it. I am using javascript and onChange event to accomplish it. But the code is not working in any of the browsers.

Here is The javascript function I am using in the head section of the document:

```
function addField() 
 {
 alert("Hello");
 var num=document.forms["myForm"]["timePerDay"].value;
   for(var i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
    var element = document.createElement("input");


    element.setAttribute("type", input);
    element.setAttribute("name", time[] );

    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
    }
    }
```

And Select field is:

```
 <select name="timePerDay" onChange="javascript:addField();"> 
<option selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<span id="fooBar">
</span>
```

It seems like onChange is not firing at all in any browser as I tried to put alert message in the JS function and even it is not working. So can you please tell me what is the problem.
 You can see the page at : http://motushealth.com/form1.html

PS: 
I am using another JS function on the form to validate it and it works on Onsubmit . It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a syntax error here: `element.setAttribute("name", time[] );` `time[]` is valid in php, but not in js.

**EDIT:**

The alternate approach is to not use inline js (`...onClick='javascript:addField();'...`). Instead do the following on `window.onload` or better, on the `onDomReady` event.

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {  /* or window.addEventListener */
    document.getElementById('timePerDay').onchange = addField;  /* or addEventListener */
};
```

And markup can be:

```
<select id="timePerDay" name="timePerDay"> 
    <option selected="selected">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think that's the only problem he's having.  I fiddled it and addField just isn't being called.  It works to put a simple 'alert' in the onchange handler tho.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes problem is that function is not even being called onChange. Rest is secondary issue.

Comment: it works actually. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/6HQUA/. The only thing - you have to place the js code before the markup, since otherwise `addField` won't be referenced from the markup. You can check it by placing js code in the 'JavaScript' box in fiddle - you'll get an error.

Comment: and...the best thing would be to not use inline js. See the edit for the alternate approach

Comment: I don't think inline JS is a poor practice, there was a problem in the syntax and it has nothing to do with inline JS.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with code for over two hours I finally found the problem. To my surprise the problem was in the code it self of JS. It seems like if there is any problem in JS code the whole function doesn't work and  is not even called onChange.

1. First problem was in the name so I changed

   element.setAttribute("name", time[] ) to element.setAttribute("name", timer[] )
2. Secondly there was a logical error in type so I changed

   element.setAttribute("type", input) to element.setAttribute("type", text);
   Thanks for all your help. I love this great community. Keep Rocking.
   Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because the function `addField()` is simply not loaded due to the `SyntaxError` occurred at `time[]` which has unexpected token `]`.

One tip for debugging this kind of problem is to always start from looking at the console log in **Web Inspector** (if you are using Chrome/Safari) or **Firebug** (if you are using Firefox).

You may also want to consider using jQuery for these kinds of tasks. Specifically, look into using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: Yes Jquery is also a good option. It seems like JS is more error prone so in future I will try to use Jquery whereever possible. Thanks for the tip.